# Error building Android project

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

Can't build android project, always get this error `INSTALL PARSE FAILED MANIFEST MALFORMED`, though few days ago I was able to build and run it on Linux. Since then, nothing have changed in code, but now I'm doing this on Windows.
I've read similar questions, where they say, that the problem is in package name, it shouldn't contain capital letters. But this is not the case.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.pxlth.connector">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".StationSettings"
        android:label="@string/action_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".BluetoothEnable"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBarDialog" />

    <service
        android:name=".BackgroundService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:process=":background" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".AutoStartReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your code in an XML validator? I just did, and it says it's incorrect, which is exactly what your error suggests.

Comment: Just ran through XML validator, showed no errors

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops out to me if your manifest tag is not closed at the bottom of the .xml

Add this at the bottom:

```
</manifest>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add 4 spaces before the tag

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled a list of possible issues below. See if this resolves the issue.

1. Check if the packages are different in the class files.

   ```
   org.pxlth.connector.activity.MainActivity
   ```

   Here the MainActivity is in package named activity;

   Similarly check for service as well;
2. Check all the package if any of it has a capital letter
3. Ensure you have string values in the default `values/strings.xml` folder and not it any of the library folder, if any.
4. Also have a look at the `typos` in the activity, service's name